# Flutter You need to have compileSdk set to at least 28 in your module error

Tags: android, flutter, androidx

I read all of this problem solutions, but it doesn't any change on my project

> **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

**build.gradle:**

```
compileSdkVersion 29

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "xx.xxx.XXXXXXXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.enableR8=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

**gradle.wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

**gradle version:**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
}
```

**pubspec.yaml:**

```
module:
    androidX:true
```

project structure:

[image]

> **Invalidate Caches/Restart**

## POST UPDATED

My **pubspec.yaml** dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  states_rebuilder: ^1.7.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc
  flutter_sms: ^1.1.0
  uuid: ^2.0.4
  avatar_glow: ^1.1.0
  url_launcher: ^5.2.7
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  fluro: ^1.5.1
  path_provider: ^1.4.5
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
  sqflite: any
  intl: ^0.16.0
  circular_reveal_animation: ^1.1.3
  expandable: ^3.0.1
  streaming_shared_preferences: ^1.0.1
  flutter_statusbarcolor: any
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.1
  moor_flutter: ^2.0.0
  moor: ^2.1.0
  flare_flutter: ^1.7.3
  chopper: ^3.0.1
  logging: ^0.11.3+2
  connectivity: ^0.4.5+6
  built_value: ^7.0.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  oktoast: ^2.2.0
  sms: ^0.2.4
  flutter_html: ^0.11.0
  animator: ^1.0.0+2
  #flutter_downloader: ^1.3.3
  audioplayer: ^0.5.2
  mobx: ^0.3.9+3
  flutter_mobx: ^0.3.3+3
  permission_handler: ^4.0.0
  flutter_wordpress: ^0.1.4
  device_info: ^0.4.1+2
  #device_info: ^0.2.1 #https://github.com/flutter/plugins
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.7.2
  moor_generator: ^2.1.1
  chopper_generator: ^3.0.2
  built_value_generator: ^7.0.0
  json_serializable: ^3.2.3
  hermes: ^3.0.0
  mobx_codegen: ^0.3.10+1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Which flutter dependencies do you have?

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin is your mean which library i used in application?

Comment: yes, show your pubspec.yaml dependencies

Comment: @IgorKharakhordin , my post updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your **Compile sdk version 29** of build.gradle: to **Compile sdk version 28**